# Песни рандомно пропадают из MediaStore после сканирования MediaScanner'ом

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, mp3

Редактирую теги, затем сканирую таким образом:

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, path, null, null);
```

Изменения сохраняются, но рандомно файлы пропадают из mediaStore (не всегда). Лечится полным пересканированием библиотеки. Куда копать, не представляю?